# Сконвертировать XML (SOAP-ответ) в JSON

Tags: python, json, xml

Сервис, у которого я запрашиваю данные, может возвращать длинный список документов, например, такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<vpuStatusReply>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795174117"/>
<vpuNumber value="062202"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:19:05"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795174757"/>
<vpuNumber value="062203"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:23:32"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795175323"/>
<vpuNumber value="062204"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:28:58"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795179549"/>
<vpuNumber value="062205"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:52:26"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
```

Мне нужно сконвертировать его в JSON на Python. Чем можно быстро распарсить данные и сконвертировать?

json.dumps конвертирует данные не совсем так, как надо.

```
{"vpuStatusReply": {"vpu": [{"vpuID": {"@value": "795174117"}, "vpuNumber": {"@value": "062202"}, "vpuStateID": {"@value": "314"}, "vpuState": {"@value": "\u0421\u043e\u0433\u043b\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d"}, "vpuNeedForECP": {"@value": "0"}, "vpuLastOper": {"@value": "10.06.2018 07:19:05"}, "docPrice": {"@value": "0"}}, {"vpuID": {"@value": "795174757"}, "vpuNumber": {"@value": "062203"}, "vpuStateID": {"@value": "314"}, "vpuState": {"@value": "\u0421\u043e\u0433\u043b\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d"}, "vpuNeedForECP": {"@value": "0"}, "vpuLastOper": {"@value": "10.06.2018 07:23:32"}, "docPrice": {"@value": "0"}}, {"vpuID": {"@value": "795175323"}, "vpuNumber": {"@value": "062204"}, "vpuStateID": {"@value": "314"}, "vpuState": {"@value": "\u0421\u043e\u0433\u043b\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d"}, "vpuNeedForECP": {"@value": "0"}, "vpuLastOper": {"@value": "10.06.2018 07:28:58"}, "docPrice": {"@value": "0"}}, {"vpuID": {"@value": "795179549"}, "vpuNumber": {"@value": "062205"}, "vpuStateID": {"@value": "314"}, "vpuState": {"@value": "\u0421\u043e\u0433\u043b\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d"}, "vpuNeedForECP": {"@value": "0"}, "vpuLastOper": {"@value": "10.06.2018 07:52:26"}, "docPrice": {"@value": "0"}}, {"vpuID": {"@value": "795180736"}, "vpuNumber": {"@value": "062206"}, "vpuStateID": {"@value": "314"}
```

Comment: А есть причины, по которым парсится XML, а не используется библиотека для SOAP, например, zeep(http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/index.html#)

Comment: @Alex Titov, я не знаю, как для этого использовать zeep. В WSDL-описании сервиса нет ничего кроме описания двух функций, которые отправляют запрос как текст. Основная функция это GetBlock(login, password, text). Больше в WSDL нет ничего полезного.

Comment: А клиентом zeep удается "залогинится", может потом "проявятся" методы? И вызвать у клиента `.wsdl.dump()` не пробовали?

Comment: @Alex Titov, клиент логинится, отправляет запросы и получает ответы. wsdl.dump() никаких дополнительных методов не показывает. Вот результат: https://pastebin.com/DGmwxj42

Comment: Мда... у меня как-то нужные функции видны... Попробуйте к клиента известную функцию вызвать, вдруг получится...  `КЛИЕНТ.service.какая-то_функция(...)`

Comment: Впрочем, судя по ответу SOAP (приведенном в другом вопросе), там, может, только эти функции (GetBlock/SendBlock) и есть?  Так что ответ вообще к SOAP не относится, просто авторы интерфейса XML внутрь SOAP засунули???

Comment: @Alex Titov, авторы засунули xml внутри SOAP-ответов